# Dojo1.8 - request php file without any inputs

Tags: php, dojo, pdo

1. I had difficultly requesting php file to process without any inputs.
   And I m using PDO in login.php
   The error I get is"Unable to load processing.php, status:500".

main.php:-

```
<head>
    <?php require_once '../scripts/login.php';?> //require action
<head>
<body>
<div id='line1'></div>

require(["dojo/request","dojo/domReady!"],                      
function(request)
{ready(function()
    {request('processing.php').then( //request action
     function(response){dom.byId(line1).innerHTML=response;},
     function(error){alert(error);
 });
    ......
</body>
```

processing.php:-

```
<?php
    echo "By default, fetch mk7BC data<br/>";
echo 
"<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>
<tr style='background-color:lightblue; font-weight:normal; font-size:small;'>
    <th style='width:40px'>ID</th>
    <th style='width:80px'>SN</th>
    <th style='width:100px'>Tested</th>
    <th style='width:40px'>Jig</th>
    <th style='width:80px'>Card</th>
    <th style='width:40px'>Batch</th>
    <th style='width:40px'>COM</th>
    <th style='width:40px'>3rdCOM</th>
    <th style='width:40px'>IO34</th>
    <th style='width:40px'>Comment</th>
</tr>";
    try
    (
        $dbh-> query('use testdata1970_10');
    $color='1';     
        foreach($dbh->query('call getallusers();') as $row)
        {if($color==1)
    {echo "<tr style='background-color:lightyellow; font-weight:lighter; 
            font-size:x-small;'>";
    $color='2';
        }
    else
            {echo"<tr style='background-color:lightgreen; font-weight:lighter;
            font-size:x-small;'>";
    $color='1';
    }

        echo
        "<td>{$row['idtest']}</td>
        <td>{$row['SN']}</td>
        <td>{$row['time_tested']}</td>
        <td>{$row['id_jig']}</td>
        <td>{$row['mfg_code']}</td>
        <td>{$row['batch_no']}</td>
        <td>{$row['com_status']}</td>
        <td>{$row['3rdcom_status']}</td>
        <td>{$row['IO34_status']}</td>
        <td>{$row['comment']}</td>
        </tr>";
            }
     echo "</table>";
    )
 ?>
```

login.php:-

```
    <?php
         dbname=testdata1970_10;
     $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost; Port=3306';
     $user = 'root';
     $pswd = '';
     $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pswd,
         array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, TRUE));
         $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
         PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
 ?>
```

Please advise Thanks
 clement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackoverflow is great for specific, "how do I do X?" questions. It is not very good for "here's all my code, help me find the error!". You need to make an effort to locate the problem yourself, then ask a specific question.

For example, is it a problem with your Javascript? Or is it a problem with your PHP? Perhaps a problem with your SQL?

In this case, you say that opening processing.php returns error 500. That means the error probably doesn't have anything to do with your Javascript. Instead, it's probably your web server having problems running your PHP script.

What could be wrong with processing.php? Does it have any syntax errors? When you open processing.php in your browser, you may get a nice error message with some clues. Or perhaps your text editor highlights errors? If not, try running

```
php -l processing.php
```

This checks your file for syntax errors. You'll probably get something like:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '{' on line 18
```

Looks like you need to replace the `(` with a `{` on line 18!

So you fix that, `php -l` again and you see the same error (almost) on line 47. Fix that. Repeat. Looks like you have a `try` without a corresponding `catch`! Fix that. Repeat.

In the end, perhaps you still have a problem - but now you've made an effort to locate the problem, and you can ask a better question.

For example, where does $dbh in processing.php come from? Are you including login.php at the top of processing.php?

Comment: Hi Frode. Thanks for your input. Now it all worked. $dbh come from login.php and I require_once login.php in main.php. When it did not worked, why do I have to do require_once login.php, not just in main.php but also in processing.php. I read that $GLOBALS("variable") is made available across all scripts and php files. So if login.php is not require_once in processing.php, I would make global $dbh; Still it did not work. It seems that the only way to work by require_once login.php in all php files. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks Clement

Comment: @user1739825 Yes, you have to require login.php in processing.php if you want to use $dbh. Nothing is remembered between two requests. In your case, you first do one request for main.php. A little while later, you do a request for processing.php. Nothing is shared or remembered between these requests, they don't know about each other. Globals only exist within one request "session".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input. Now it all worked. $dbh come from login.php and I require_once login.php in main.php and processing.php. However, I do not understand why login.php needed to be required_once again in processing.php as the scripts in login.php is available to all scripts from main.php. Since $dbh is in global scope in login.php and login.php is require_once, therefore I would require_once login.php in main.php, not processing.php.
For eg;

```
login.php - <?php $dbh="blah"?>
main.php - <?php require_once login.php?>
A.php - <?php $dbh... ?>
B.php - <?php $dbh... ?>
C.php - <?php $dbh... ?>
```

and so on. I just want login.php to be avaiable once and for all, not to repeat require_once in every scripts. I read that "When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward." in PHP.net. Please correct if I am wrong. Thanks Clement